# Retornar zero quando não encontrar registro

Tags: sql

Tenho uma tabela que basicamente existem a Filial, o Código da Receita, o período dessa receita e o valor da receita.

Preciso que ao gerar o select ele me traga informações do período escolhido e dos dois meses anteriores.

No select que fiz, funciona apenas quando o código da receita existe para o 3 períodos. Quando existe um código de receita no período escolhido que não existe nos outros dois meses anteriores, o select não retorna nada.

Eu preciso que os meses anteriores que não houverem esse código de receite, seja retornado 0.

Segue meu select:

```
SELECT AA.ZZV_FILIAL,
   AA.ZZV_PERIOD,
   AA.ZZV_TREC,
   AA.ZZV_DREC,
   AA.ZZV_CCUSTO,
   AA.ZZV_NOME,
   SUM(AA.ZZV_VALOR) AS 'PERIODO1',
   CASE
       WHEN SUM(BB.ZZV_VALOR) IS NULL THEN '0'
       ELSE SUM(BB.ZZV_VALOR)
   END AS 'PERIODO2',
   CASE
       WHEN SUM(CC.ZZV_VALOR) IS NULL THEN '0'
       ELSE SUM(CC.ZZV_VALOR)
   END AS 'PERIODO3'
FROM ZZV020 AS AA
INNER JOIN ZZV020 AS BB ON (BB.ZZV_PERIOD = '201905'
                            AND BB.ZZV_FILIAL = '0177')
AND (BB.ZZV_TREC = AA.ZZV_TREC
     AND BB.ZZV_CCUSTO = AA.ZZV_CCUSTO)
INNER JOIN ZZV020 AS CC ON (CC.ZZV_PERIOD = '201904'
                            AND CC.ZZV_FILIAL = '0177')
AND (CC.ZZV_TREC = AA.ZZV_TREC
     AND CC.ZZV_CCUSTO = AA.ZZV_CCUSTO)
WHERE AA.ZZV_FILIAL = '0177'
  AND AA.ZZV_PERIOD = '201906'
  AND AA.D_E_L_E_T_ = ''
GROUP BY AA.ZZV_FILIAL,
         AA.ZZV_PERIOD,
         AA.ZZV_TREC,
         AA.ZZV_DREC,
         AA.ZZV_CCUSTO,
         AA.ZZV_NOME
ORDER BY AA.ZZV_TREC,
         AA.ZZV_CCUSTO
```

Desde já agradeço pela ajuda!

Comment: Rafael, dê mais detalhes por favor, como qual SGBD está usando, um exemplo no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) seria interessante tb

Comment: "*funciona apenas quando o código da receita existe para o 3 períodos*", o código da receita que você fala são as colunas: **AA.ZZV_VALOR**, **BB.ZZV_VALOR** e **CC.ZZV_VALOR**?

Comment: A função COALESCE faz o que você precisa. COALESCE(campo, 0).

Answer (score 0):

Ola como já referiram deverias colocar qual a base de dados, deduzo que seja MySQL, partilho o que me parece ser a solução, apesar de não teres muita informação:

```
SELECT AA.ZZV_FILIAL,
   AA.ZZV_PERIOD,
   AA.ZZV_TREC,
   AA.ZZV_DREC,
   AA.ZZV_CCUSTO,
   AA.ZZV_NOME,
   SUM(AA.ZZV_VALOR) AS 'PERIODO1',
   IFNULL(SUM(BB.ZZV_VALOR),0) AS 'PERIODO2',
   IFNULL(SUM(CC.ZZV_VALOR),0) AS 'PERIODO3',
FROM ZZV020 AS AA
INNER JOIN ZZV020 AS BB ON (BB.ZZV_PERIOD = '201905'
                            AND BB.ZZV_FILIAL = '0177')
AND (BB.ZZV_TREC = AA.ZZV_TREC
     AND BB.ZZV_CCUSTO = AA.ZZV_CCUSTO)
INNER JOIN ZZV020 AS CC ON (CC.ZZV_PERIOD = '201904'
                            AND CC.ZZV_FILIAL = '0177')
AND (CC.ZZV_TREC = AA.ZZV_TREC
     AND CC.ZZV_CCUSTO = AA.ZZV_CCUSTO)
WHERE AA.ZZV_FILIAL = '0177'
  AND AA.ZZV_PERIOD = '201906'
  AND AA.D_E_L_E_T_ = ''
GROUP BY AA.ZZV_FILIAL,
         AA.ZZV_PERIOD,
         AA.ZZV_TREC,
         AA.ZZV_DREC,
         AA.ZZV_CCUSTO,
         AA.ZZV_NOME
ORDER BY AA.ZZV_TREC,
         AA.ZZV_CCUSTO
```